# VBA - Error when using Application.Evaluate on Long Formula

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

Say I have a long formula on some cell in Excel

> =IF(SUM(D3:D6)>1,"A-B-C-D-E-F-G-H-I-J-K-L-M-N-O-P-Q-R-S-T-U-V-W-X-Y-Z 01",
>   IF(SUM(D3:D6)>1,"A-B-C-D-E-F-G-H-I-J-K-L-M-N-O-P-Q-R-S-T-U-V-W-X-Y-Z
>   02",
>   IF(SUM(D3:D6)>1,"A-B-C-D-E-F-G-H-I-J-K-L-M-N-O-P-Q-R-S-T-U-V-W-X-Y-Z
>   03",
>   IF(SUM(D3:D6)>1,"A-B-C-D-E-F-G-H-I-J-K-L-M-N-O-P-Q-R-S-T-U-V-W-X-Y-Z
>   04",
>   IF(SUM(D3:D6)>1,"A-B-C-D-E-F-G-H-I-J-K-L-M-N-O-P-Q-R-S-T-U-V-W-X-Y-Z
>   05",
>   IF(SUM(D3:D6)>1,"A-B-C-D-E-F-G-H-I-J-K-L-M-N-O-P-Q-R-S-T-U-V-W-X-Y-Z
>   06",
>   IF(SUM(D3:D6)>1,"A-B-C-D-E-F-G-H-I-J-K-L-M-N-O-P-Q-R-S-T-U-V-W-X-Y-Z
>   07",
>   IF(SUM(D3:D6)>1,"A-B-C-D-E-F-G-H-I-J-K-L-M-N-O-P-Q-R-S-T-U-V-W-X-Y-Z
>   08",
>   IF(SUM(D3:D6)>1,"A-B-C-D-E-F-G-H-I-J-K-L-M-N-O-P-Q-R-S-T-U-V-W-X-Y-Z
>   09",
>   IF(SUM(D3:D6)>1,"A-B-C-D-E-F-G-H-I-J-K-L-M-N-O-P-Q-R-S-T-U-V-W-X-Y-Z
>   10",
>   IF(SUM(D3:D6)>1,"A-B-C-D-E-F-G-H-I-J-K-L-M-N-O-P-Q-R-S-T-U-V-W-X-Y-Z
>   11",
>   IF(SUM(D3:D6)>1,"A-B-C-D-E-F-G-H-I-J-K-L-M-N-O-P-Q-R-S-T-U-V-W-X-Y-Z
>   12",
>   IF(SUM(D3:D6)>1,"A-B-C-D-E-F-G-H-I-J-K-L-M-N-O-P-Q-R-S-T-U-V-W-X-Y-Z
>   13",
>   IF(SUM(D3:D6)>1,"A-B-C-D-E-F-G-H-I-J-K-L-M-N-O-P-Q-R-S-T-U-V-W-X-Y-Z
>   14","no" ))))))))))))))

and I run the following VBA code

```
Private Sub ExecuteFormula()
    Dim sFormula As String, vReturn As Variant
    sFormula = Selection.Formula

    vReturn = Application.Evaluate(sFormula)
    If VarType(vReturn) <> vbError Then
        MsgBox vReturn, vbInformation
    Else
        MsgBox "Error", vbExclamation
    End If
End Sub
```

then I get "Error". For shorter formulas it works just fine, so I was wondering if there was a way to evaluate long formulas (in general) using VBA.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [Microsoft documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193019.aspx) this is what is causing your error:

> Parameters
>
> Name: *Name*
>
> Required/Optional: Required
>
> Data Type: Variant
>
> Description: A formula or the name of the object, using the naming convention of Microsoft Excel. The length of the name must be **less than or equal to 255 characters**.

*Note that in the description it also says you can use "The name of the object" instead of a formula.*

However even further reading  will help narrow down what the options are for evaluation long formulas.  This next section gives us what "names" can be used with this method:

> The following types of names in Microsoft Excel can be used with this method:
>
> - Formulas.
> - A1-style references. You can use any reference to a single
>   cell in A1-style notation. All references are considered to be
>   absolute references.
> - Ranges. You can use the range, intersect, and
>   union operators (colon, space, and comma, respectively) with
>   references.
> - Defined names. You can specify any name in the language
>   of the macro.
> - External references. You can use the ! operator to
>   refer to a cell or to a name defined in another workbook — for
>   example, Evaluate("[BOOK1.XLS]Sheet1!A1").
> - Chart Objects. You can
>   specify any chart object name, such as "Legend", "Plot Area", or
>   "Series 1", to access the properties and methods of that object. For
>   example, Charts("Chart1").Evaluate("Legend").Font.Name returns the
>   name of the font used in the legend.

And then specific examples:

```
[a1].Value = 25 
Evaluate("A1").Value = 25 
 
trigVariable = [SIN(45)] 
trigVariable = Evaluate("SIN(45)") 
 
Set firstCellInSheet = Workbooks("BOOK1.XLS").Sheets(4).[A1] 
Set firstCellInSheet = _ 
    Workbooks("BOOK1.XLS").Sheets(4).Evaluate("A1")
```

Taking all that in shows us that we can use the cell's address to perform the calculation instead of bringing over the entire formula.

This means we can modify your `sub` to use the cell address:

```
Private Sub ExecuteFormula()
    Dim sFormula As String, vReturn As Variant
    sFormula = Selection.Address ' use the cells address not the formula

    vReturn = Application.Evaluate(sFormula)
    If VarType(vReturn) <> vbError Then
        MsgBox vReturn, vbInformation
    Else
        MsgBox "Error", vbExclamation
    End If
End Sub
```